# How to make condition to find AccessibilityId?

Tags: java, appium

I create some code to find AccessibilityId after swipe action, but it did "not" go into my while condition. ***How to make condition to find AccessibilityId?***

This is scenario I want.

```
1.Launch app, there is no test1_action buttons (AccessibilityId = test1_action)
2.To Click test1_action, will repeat swipe "i" times till find AccessibilityId.
3.After "i" times swiping, if there will be test1_action button then it will click it
```

iOS/iPhone/Appium

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
int i = 0;
while 
(!driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("test1_action")).isDisplayed()) {
    swipe(331, 544, 50, 544, 2);
    i++;
        }
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("test1_action"))).click();
```

When i run this, I faced below error

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element
>   could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Comment: Correct one thing, it did "not" go into my while condition -> it did not run "swipe(331, 544, 50, 544, 2);" in the while loop. Of course, swipe() works fine with other my functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element is not present you will get a [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) on attempt to call [isDisplayed()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#isDisplayed--) function, consider amending your code to look like:

```
while (driver.findElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("test1_action")).size() == 0 && i < 100) {
    swipe(331, 544, 50, 544, 2);
    i++;
}
```

You can also consider using [SwipeWhileNotFound](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation-+SwipeWhileNotFound) method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going into while loop, because the error 'NoSuchElementException' is being thrown from 'driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("test1_action")).isDisplayed()' line (you may cross-check that first). As the first iteration itself the element doesn't present and hence isDisplayed() will give error.

Solution to this:

 1) Create separate method to check the element exist or not which checks for the element present or not in try/catch block and should returns the true or false. That method can be used here to check the existence of element in while loop.

2) Instead of 'driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("test1_action")).isDisplayed()' use 'driver.findElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("test1_action")).size()>0', which does not throw any error and check the element exist or not as well.

Note: Put some exit/break condition in your while loop, when trying above two solution else it would go in infinite loop.